# How to create graph at bottom of any layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i want to implement graph below layout at the bottom, how can i do this i try a lot but graph is not showing. this is my code . Thanks in Advance.

**XML file**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow
            android:id="@+id/fancyCoverFlow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            fcf:maxRotation="45"
            fcf:scaleDownGravity="0.5"
            fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
            fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
            fcf:unselectedScale="0.4" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fist_lay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fancyCoverFlow"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_one"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/testview_big"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/statistic_spinner"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/stats"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/statistic_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/statistic_spinner"
                    android:background="@drawable/share_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!--
         <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </ListView>
            -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_full_Bottel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Relative_Full_Bottel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageFullBottle"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/full_bottle_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtFullBottlee"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageFullBottle"
                        android:text="" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Relative_Half_Bottel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageHalfBottle"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/half_bottle_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHalfBottle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageHalfBottle"
                        android:text="" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Relative_Injection"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageInjection"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/injection_and" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtInjection"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageInjection"
                        android:text="" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Relative_FoodStat"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageFoodStat"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/food_stat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtFoodStat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageFoodStat"
                        android:text="" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Relative_DipperStat"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageDipperStat"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/dipper_stat" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDipperStat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDipperStat"
                        android:text="" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chart_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MY JAVA CODE**

```
/**
 * GRAPH WORK
 */
private void openChart() {

    int count = 5;
    Date[] dt = new Date[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, i + 1);
        dt[i] = gc.getTime();
    }

    int[] visits = { 2000, 2500, 2700, 2100, 2800 };
    int[] views = { 2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 3200 };

    // Creating TimeSeries for Visits
    TimeSeries visitsSeries = new TimeSeries("Visits");

    // Creating TimeSeries for Views
    TimeSeries viewsSeries = new TimeSeries("Views");

    // Adding data to Visits and Views Series
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
        visitsSeries.add(dt[i], visits[i]);
        viewsSeries.add(dt[i], views[i]);
    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    // Adding Visits Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(visitsSeries);

    // Adding Visits Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(viewsSeries);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize visitsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer visitsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    visitsRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    visitsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    visitsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    visitsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    visitsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize viewsSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer viewsRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    viewsRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    viewsRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    viewsRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    viewsRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    viewsRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Visits vs Views Chart");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Days");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Count");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    // Adding visitsRenderer and viewsRenderer to multipleRenderer
    // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to
    // multipleRenderer
    // should be same
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(visitsRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(viewsRenderer);

    // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout

    // Creating a Time Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(
            getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, "dd-MMM-yyyy");

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    // Setting a click event listener for the graph
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutParams and add Rule for mChart View after that add it to chartContainer

Comment: RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
rl.addView(mChart);  i try this but not any change

Comment: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLay‌​out.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); chartContainer.addView(mChart); try this

Comment: chartContainer.addView(mChart);or lay.addView(mChart);

Comment: chartContainer.addView(mChart,lay); becouse you add rule for your chartContainer parrent and should be relativelayout try this for me was ok

Comment: not work for me i try this..    chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container1);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
  chartContainer.addView(mChart,lay);

Comment: yes becouse  chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container1);  is linearLayout try to make it RelativeLayout from xml and also from java class will be ok after

Comment: If you really want to be LinearLayout you can work with gravity but I sugest you to make it Relative

Comment: I try this but chartContainer parent is liner layout its not working. chartContainer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart_container1);RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
  chartContainer.addView(mChart, lay);

Comment: if you use RelativeLayout for chartContainer just set the size with 200x200 in xml and RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 100, 100); and you will see that it's working. Just to test it...

Comment: yes, when i give (200,200) so its working fine.. so what should i do for all devices.

Comment: I think aChartEngine library force your chart to be match_parrent so probably you have to implement a fucntion to force layout to have a defined size for the standard resolutions I sugest you to make it for hdpi, xhdpi, xxdpi and by default give a value for a resolution that is more or equal to xxhdpi.